# Deactive lazy load for owl carousel after it is already displayed

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

Hey guys so I have a problem I really can't solve. I am using owl carousel on a product detail page (pdp) to show multiple images of a product. Since I want to start an AB Test changing the display and amount of images, I use a CSS code to hide the control buttons for the owl carousel and show all pictures at once and don't really use the slider option anymore:

[preview slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3nrY.jpg)

But now I have the problem that the first images are preloaded but all the new once I added are having a loading animation because of lazy load.

When I click on the control buttons they are loaded so I thought why not faking it with a click in jQuery but owl carousel doesn't seem to recognize it

```
jQuery('.owl-next').trigger('click');
```

This code works on all other elements but not on the control buttons. Is there some way you know how to manually activate the loading of all images?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I just found a workaround to load the value of the data-src attribute (because the image exists there) into a src attribute I just created:

 `var newthumbnail = jQuery('.owl-item.loading:nth-child(1) .item a img').attr('data-src');
        jQuery('.owl-item.loading:nth-child(1) .item a img').prop('src', newthumbnail);`

Answer (score 0):

From the API [events](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html) documentation example:

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel();

// Go to the next item
$('.customNextBtn').click(function() {
    owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
})
```

With a bit of luck, all you need is something like this:

```
owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
```

Comment: I already tried this but he doesn't seem to get the click, thats the main problem :( 
It is as if something inside of owl carousel would realize that I fake the click and wants a real click.